# Data binding in directive isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a directive with isolated scope, but I'm not able to get it working.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zf8mL103/4/)

I want to isolate age model in a directive scope. I want to perform some business logic on that model and then set that model to parent binding. I hope the fiddle is explanatory.

I am also adding a button to the template which when clicked should invoke a submit function:

```
<button ng-click="submit()">click me</button>
```

It seems the button is working fine, but why is `$scope.$watch()` is not begin triggered? In a normal situation, if I change the view value it will automatically update the model value. But now it isn't.

Comment: The jsFiddle is not working at all. Check the console there, it's reporting all kinds of errors.

Comment: Yes I am not able to get it working. I hope you understood what I want to achieve.
Help me in this I am struggling from a long time

Comment: You misunderstood: AngularJs is not even loading in that jsfiddle

Comment: looking on your fiddle it doesnt making sense , because you tring to watch something which already in your directive, can you explain exactly what you want to do

Comment: Also, why are you assigning user.name to var age... where does 'user' even come from??

Comment: @Plantface
The user is for demo purpose only I am creating a reusable directive
Why I am watching that because that content will be markdown as user type I will convert that markdown and show preview to user
The markdown content will be stored in content.raw and html rendered content in content.html
After that I will set this content model to parent scope variable.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right fiddle, there isn't even a button like you mentioned...

Comment: @pixelbits The right fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zf8mL103/4/

Comment: get better organized before posting questions next time

Answer (score 1):

`$watch` requires a dollar sign, and you pass either a function or a string that is evaluated on your scope, i.e.:

```
$scope.$watch('age', function(value) {
```

There are many more errors in your code, for instance you don't have a declared variable called 'age' so this line will reference `window.age` and give you an error because it is undefined, you need to say `$scope.age` I think:

```
age = age+10;
```

It just looks like your updated fiddle is a playground, hope these point you in the right direction.  I'd recommend going through the [egghead.io angular videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lx7ycjC8qjE&list=PLP6DbQBkn9ymGQh2qpk9ImLHdSH5T7yw7).